Persisting a more complex object as bloc state in hydrated bloc?
So I decided on a BLoC pattern for my flutter app and so far it worked.
But then I also introduced the hydrated bloc plugin for persistence.
All I can find as examples in hydrated bloc is the same README integer counter example over and over again. I am trying to persist a state object of a bloc, but I am having trouble achieving it.
Scenario is a login.
I have login states which I use in a bloc as reaction towards responses from a server.
Before the persistence part simply with bloc, everything worked. But now I am struggling to persist my login states.
I did successfully persist the login states in a first try in a seperate cubit as a boolean but it felt kind of unclean to not persist the proper LoginState and outsource it to said boolean in said cubit. So I wanted to switch to persisting the state of the bloc.
class LoginServiceBloc extends HydratedBloc<LoginEventType, LoginStateType> {
  LoginService? service;

  LoginServiceBloc(this.service) : super(LoginIdleState()) {
    on<LoginRequestEvent>((event, emit) async {
      log("ProductFetchInit");
      emit(LoginLoadingState());
      log("ProductFetch");
      ResponseModel responseModel = await service!.loginUser(event.server, event.user, event.org, event.password);
      if (responseModel is UserResponseModel) {
        emit(LoginLoadedState(responseModel));
      } else if (responseModel is ErrorResponseModel) {
        emit(LoginErrorState(responseModel));
      }
    });
    on<LoginErrorEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(LoginErrorState(ErrorResponseModel(event.code, event.msg)));
    });
  }

  @override
  LoginStateType fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return json['state'];
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(LoginStateType state) {
    return {state};
  }
}

class LoginStateType extends Equatable {
  final ResponseModel responseModel;

  LoginStateType fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginStateType(json['responseModel']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(LoginStateType state) {
    return {'responseModel': state.responseModel.toJson()};
  }

  const LoginStateType(this.responseModel);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [responseModel];
}

class LoginIdleState extends LoginStateType {
  const LoginIdleState(super.responseModel);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class LoginLoadingState extends LoginStateType {
  const LoginLoadingState(super.responseModel);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class LoginLoadedState extends LoginStateType {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [super.responseModel];

  @override
  const LoginLoadedState(super.response);
}

class LoginErrorState extends LoginStateType {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [super.responseModel];

  @override
  const LoginErrorState(super.response);
}

The states themselves do have models for a response or f.e. an error with an error code and error message.
Dart is my first language without reflection or more simple json transformations so I am struggling with the hydrated bloc json part at the moment.
I simply do not understand what I need to properly persist my Login States.
Maybe I am missing the obvious here.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.
